# Change InfoPath edit Form URL name to id

Tags: infopath

Is it possible to change InfoPath edit Form URL from filename to ID?

From

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/Leave%20Request/LR33.xml
```

to something like

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/Leave%20Request/ID/33.xml
```

Cause: In my case filename and ID are different for some case.